# Deleting App_Data for Orchard CMS on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, sql-server-ce, orchardcms

I have created a website on azure running Orchard CMS using a SQL Compact database. Seems to be working fine. However, I just want to use this as a testing ground for modules that I need to online / in the cloud. And being a fairly useless developer, I have already broken it. On my local machine, or on IIS, I just cry a little, delete the App_Data folder, and carry on. All good.

So my question is, is there a way of deleting this folder on Azure? Or doing something similar? I really have no idea how Azure works, first time using it. The App_Data folder is where the Sql-Server-CE file is stored.

Any help or tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context of your question I assume you are working with [Windows Azure WebSites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/) and you have created Orchard from the gallery.

If so, then all you need to do is login with FTP and delete the app_data folder again. You can create credentials for login here:

[image: Azure WebSites credentials]

Note that before you have credentials the link will be "Create deployment credentials"

And you can find the FTP hostname here:

[image: Azure websites ftp host]

You can use any FTP client to connect to the FTP.

You can also edit your site with WebMatrix.

[Here is a great explanation of the Deployment Credentials](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials).

Comment: Cheers for that, didn't know anything about deployment credentials, life saver. That little lightning cloud is a sneaky icon, hiding in plain sight... totally missed it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually delete the App_Data folder while developing you have a few options:

- For Azure Websites you can [connect through FTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploading-downloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs.aspx) and delete the folder
- For Web Roles (Cloud Services) you can [connect through RDP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx) and delete the folder (don't do this for live deployments since changes through RDP are not persisted).

But why not do everything locally an simply use WebDeploy/WebMatrix to see how it runs in the cloud?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the prompt reply, I connected via FTP, great little tutorial you linked. And I'm pretty new to Azure and just saw that Orchard was in the gallery and got excited and started clicking buttons and ended up with a running site. I'll have to check out other ways of doing it, but this seemed pretty awesome. And if I wasn't such a dumbass and failed to read anything about Azures ftp'ing, would have been totally straightforward. But I will check it all out ^^ Thanks again